# How to disable Mui-focusVisible Mui-focused for an AccordionSummary element?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm using a custom element for changing the group name of an AccordionSummary.

[The UI in normal mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p0W3E.png)

[Element code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dhRFj.png)

Upon clicking the edit button for changing name, mui-focused mui-focusVisible property is passed to AccordionSummary which creates a grey background over the element. Upon clicking save, the mui-focused property is removed again. However, when trying to submit pressing enter and not clicking save, mui-focused stays and AccordionSummary is greyed/focused even in non-edit mode.

[Mui-focused upon edit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c69fq.png)

[Mui-focused/focusVisible element code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CMKaD.png)

[Greyed UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D4HtS.png)

I have also tried using a modal form instead for changing the group name. Got the exact same issue of a persistent mui-focused upon submitting by pressing enter.

Is there any way where I could override/disable focused property? I don't want to preventDefault for enter keypress because of bad UX. Sharing the relevant code below.

```
const AccordionSummary = withStyles((theme) => ({
    content: {
    marginTop: theme.spacing(1),
    marginBottom: theme.spacing(1),
    '&$expanded': {
      marginTop: theme.spacing(1),
      marginBottom: theme.spacing(1),
    },
  },
  expanded: {},
}))(MuiAccordionSummary)

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  turbineIcon: {
    marginRight: theme.spacing(2),
  },
  gap: {
    gap: theme.spacing(1),
  },
}))

const GroupSummary = ({
  onChangeGroupParameter,
}) => {
const classes = useStyles()

  const handleGroupNameValidation = (newName) => {
    return /^[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9\s_\-]+$/.test(newName)
  }

  const handleGroupNameChange = useCallback(
    (newGroupName) => {
      onChangeGroupParameter(groupId, 'group', newGroupName)
    },
    [onChangeGroupParameter, groupId]
  )
return (
    <AccordionSummary
      aria-controls={`${groupId}-content`}
      id={`${groupId}-header`}
    >
       <Box
          display="flex"
          width="100%"
          alignItems="center"
          justifyContent="center"
          flexWrap="wrap"
          className={classes.gap}
        >
          <TurbineIconButton big visual className={classes.turbineIcon} />
          <Tooltip title="Add">
            <EditableTypography
              variant="h4"
              initialValue={groupId}
              onValidate={handleGroupNameValidation}
              onSave={handleGroupNameChange}
              label="group name"
            />
          </Tooltip>
       </Box>
   </AccordionSummary>
  )
}
```

EditableTypography-

```
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  noPadding: {
    padding: 0,
  },
  iconStyle: {
    width: theme.spacing(2.5),
    height: theme.spacing(2.5),
  },
}))

const defaultOnValidate = () => true

const EditableTypography = ({
  initialValue,
  onSave,
  onValidate,
  textFieldProps,
  iconButtonProps,
  containerProps,
  ...rest
}) => {
  const classes = useStyles()

  const [value, setValue] = useState(initialValue)
  const [editing, setEditing] = useState(false)

  const handleKeyPress = useCallback(
    (e) => {
      if (e.key === 'Enter') {
        handleValueSave(value)
      } else if (e.key === 'Escape') {
        setEditing(false)
        setValue(initialValue)
      }
    },
    [handleValueSave, setEditing, setValue, initialValue, value]
  )

  const isValid = useMemo(() => onValidate(value), [onValidate, value])

  const getHelperText = useCallback(() => {
    if (value === initialValue) return 'No change'
    if (!isValid) return 'Invalid'
    return ''
  }, [isValid, value, initialValue])

  const helperText = useMemo(() => getHelperText(value), [getHelperText, value])

  const handleValueSave = useCallback(
    (value) => {
      setEditing(false)
      if (isValid) {
        onSave(value)
      }
    },
    [setEditing, onSave, isValid]
  )

  const handleTextFieldOnChange = useCallback((e) => setValue(e.target.value), [
    setValue,
  ])
  const handleSaveClick = useCallback(() => handleValueSave(value), [
    handleValueSave,
    value,
  ])

  const handleEditClick = useCallback(
    (e) => {
      e.stopPropagation()

      setEditing(true)
    },
    [setEditing]
  )

  return (
    <Box display="flex" alignItems="center" {...containerProps}>
      {editing && (
        <>
          <TextField
            autoFocus
            helperText={helperText}
            error={!isValid}
            value={value}
            variant="outlined"
            onChange={handleTextFieldOnChange}
            onKeyDown={handleKeyPress}
            className={classes.noPadding}
            {...textFieldProps}
          />
          <IconButton onClick={handleSaveClick} {...iconButtonProps}>
            <SaveIcon size="small" />
          </IconButton>
        </>
      )}
      {!editing && (
        <>
          <Typography {...rest}>{value}</Typography>
          <IconButton onClick={handleEditClick} {...iconButtonProps}>
            <EditIcon size="small" className={classes.iconStyle} />
          </IconButton>
        </>
      )}
    </Box>
  )
}
```

Modal code-

```
<EditGroupNameModal
            show={editGroupOpen}
            initialValue={groupId}
            onModalClose={handleModalClose}
            onSave={handleGroupNameChange}
          />
```

```
const EditGroupNameModal = ({ initialValue, show, onModalClose, onSave }) => {
  const classes = useStyles()

  const handleClose = () => {
    onModalClose(false)
  }

  const handleSubmit = useCallback((data) => {
    onSave(data.groupName)
    handleClose()
  })

  return (
    <Modal
      className={classes.modal}
      open={show}
      onClose={handleClose}
      onModalClose={handleClose}
    >
      <EditGroupForm
        initialValue={initialValue}
        onCancel={handleClose}
        onSubmit={handleSubmit}
      />
    </Modal>
  )
}
```

```
const EditGroupForm = ({ onCancel, initialValue, onSubmit }) => {
  const validationSchema = Yup.object().shape({
    groupName: Yup.string()
      .required('Group name is required')
      .matches(
        /^[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9\s_\-]+$/,
        'Group name should have min 2 characters and no special characters except dash (-)'
      ),
  })

  const {
    register,
    handleSubmit,
    formState: { errors, isDirty },
  } = useForm({
    defaultValues: {
      groupName: initialValue,
    },
    resolver: yupResolver(validationSchema),
  })

  const classes = useStyles()

  return (
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
        <Paper className={classes.paper}>
          <Box
            className={classes.rootBox}
            display="flex"
            flexDirection="column"
          >
            <Box mb={3}>
              <Typography variant="h4">Edit Group Name</Typography>
            </Box>
            <Box mb={3}>
              <TextField
                autoFocus
                fullWidth
                defaultValue={initialValue}
                {...register('groupName')}
                // onKeyPress={(e) => {
                //   e.key === 'Enter' && e.preventDefault()
                // }}
              />
              <span style={{ color: 'red' }}>{errors.groupName?.message}</span>
            </Box>
            <Box ml="auto">
              <Button
                style={{ marginRight: '1vw' }}
                variant="contained"
                onClick={onCancel}
              >
                Cancel
              </Button>
              <Button
                variant="contained"
                color="primary"
                type="submit"
                disabled={!isDirty}
              >
                Save
              </Button>
            </Box>
          </Box>
        </Paper>
      </form>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a sandbox?